# OpenGL Window size for drawing grid

Tags: opengl, grid, coordinates

I am trying to draw a 50x50 grid in an OpenGL window. My code for drawing the grid is

```
void GLGrid::draw() {

int y=-width;
int yIncrement = width / 50;
int x=-length;
int xIncrement = length / 50;


glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
for(y = -width; y < width; y+=yIncrement) {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(-width,y,0);
        glVertex3f(width,y,0);
    glEnd();
}

for(x = -length; x < length; x+=xIncrement) {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(-length,x,0);
        glVertex3f(length,x,0);
    glEnd();
}
}
```

Note that before I was doing x=0;x < length etc but that was making the line (the only one I see) start in the middle of the screen, rather than the very left. Also, when I draw a rectangle over the whole window, I have to start that at negative 300x300, rather than 0,0.

The only thing I see is one horizontal line across the middle of the screen. I think the problem is I don't know what my window size actually is. Whenever I print out wherever I click with

```
static void mouseEvent(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
cout<<"\nMouse Event!";
cout<<"\n\tbutton:"<<button;
cout<<"\n\tstate:"<<state;
cout<<"\n\tx:"<<x;
cout<<"\n\ty:"<<y<<"\n";
}
```

It prints out that the upper left corner is 0,0 and the bottom right corner is 300,300. So I set my GLGrid length and width to be 300 each. Should I be setting the window length and width to something else? And if so, what? I am very new to OpenGL so please forgive my ignorance. To be thorough and because I don't know if something else subtle may be the issue, I will include more code

```
static void initOpenGL() {
//set clear color to white
glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
}


/*OpenGL calls*/
static void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

if (!init)
{
    initOpenGL();
}

renderScene();

//...more code below in this function but pretty positive its irrelevant



static void renderScene() {

    drawBackground();

    drawGrid();

}


static void drawBackground() {
//draw a white rectangle for background
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(-windowMaxX, -windowMaxY, 0);
        glVertex3f(windowMaxX, -windowMaxY, 0);
        glVertex3f(windowMaxX, windowMaxY, 0);
        glVertex3f(-windowMaxX, windowMaxY, 0);
    glEnd();
}


static void drawGrid() {
    GLGrid.draw();
}
```

Comment: What are you using to get mouse events? And do you ever do any `glMultMatrix`, `glScale`, or `glTranslate` calls?

Comment: I am just doing glutMouseFunc (mouseEvent); to call that function. I don't do any multmatrix, scale, or translate, calls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are drawing your vertical lines you need to change your `x` value, not your `y` value:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(x,-length,0);
    glVertex3f(x,length,0);
glEnd();
```

There's probably more wrong, but this is one thing to change.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, that helped slightly. I see one vertical and one horizontal now :), both at the center.

Comment: If you try printing inside your loops, are you sure that your `x` and `y` values are going between -300 and 300?

Comment: Yep, they are. They are going in increments of 6.

Comment: What if you make `x` and `y` go between `-1` and `1`? (make them `floats`)

Comment: That works! So I just set float yIncrement = 2 / 50.0; and float xIncrement = 2 / 50.0; and do for(float y = -1; y < 1; y+=yIncrement). Why does this work though? And is there a way to make it more intuitive by making it go from 0 to the length/width size?

Comment: Uhh, the problem is that by default drawing coordinates go from `-1` to `1`. You could use `glOrtho` to change the perspective to something more useful by calling it like `glOrtho(0, 300, 0, 300, -1, 1);`. One annoyance that you might note is that the mouse position function just gives you the pixel value.